# Detaching thread from it self

Tags: c++, multithreading

I got some problems with multythreading, while i was creating small Direct2d library. Is there any way to detach thread from it self?
For exaple:

```
std::thread a([](){
std<<cout "thread started" << std::endl;
//here i need to destroy(detach) this thread
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by detach thread "from it self"? A thread can be detached from the `std::thread` object. Do you mean that? There is a member function to do it. What do you mean by `destroy(detach)`? Detaching doesn't cause anything to be destroyed.

Comment: @eerorika i know that i can use a.detach(), but i can not use it inside thread function, is there any way to get the same result as a.detach(), but in thread function body?

Comment: I think calling detach from within the thread may be technically possible, but is probably a very bad idea. See [this](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no standard or safe way to detach a thread from within the thread. You must either `join` or `detach` a thread object before it goes out of scope.

Based on your use case, the use of `std::async` may be a more suitable alternative, as it does not require any manual joining or detaching of a thread:

```
#include<future>

std::future<void> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, []{
        std::cout << "asynchronous call" << '\n';
});

//no detaching or joining required
```